# Select COUNT (*) fails if no result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a simple query (below) to see if there are no rows found in a table.  If there are none, then do something.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) as count FROM AT_vbc_content_status
```

However, I keep getting this error...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '*) as count FROM [name of my table] WHERE member_id= '16'' at
> line 1

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the space between **COUNT** and **(**

```
COUNT(*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space between COUNT and the parenthesis  like this: COUNT(*)

See the MySQL documentation at the link below for explanation

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/function-resolution.html

Answer (score 1):

The MySql function is `COUNT(field_name)` and there must not be any space between `COUNT` and `(*)`, So Remove the extra space between `COUNT` and `(*)`

```
$content_status_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM AT_vbc_content_status WHERE member_id= '".$_SESSION['member_id']."'";
```